# Rails - Phusion Passenger & Custom Nginx with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nginx, passenger

To add Phusion Passanger to my rails app I added gem;

```
group :production do
  gem "passenger"
end
```

Then `bundle install`.

```
2. Precompile assets
3. git add -A
4. git commit -am "passenger" 
5. git push heroku master
```

Checking..

[image]

Webserver seems working. But I would like to create custom nginx config file. [From the documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template), created 
`cp $(passenger-config about resourcesdir)/templates/standalone/config.erb nginx.conf.erb`

The reason why I want to use custom nginx is to redirection from http to https and serve static content with cloudfront etc..

Then commit and push to heroku server **BUT** nothing seems to be changed.

I also followed [this link](http://code.eklund.io/blog/2015/03/17/managing-rewrites-for-a-rails-app-on-heroku-with-nginx-plus-phusion-passenger/) but no luck.

```
** This is the custom nginx config file **
##########################################################################
#  Passenger Standalone is built on the same technology that powers
#  Passenger for Nginx, so any configuration option supported by Passenger
#  for Nginx can be applied to Passenger Standalone as well. You can do
#  this by direct editing the Nginx configuration template that is used by
#  Passenger Standalone.
#
#  This file is the original template. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
#  Instead, make a copy of this file and pass the `--nginx-config-template`
#  parameter to Passenger Standalone.
#
#  Learn more about using the Nginx configuration template at:
#  https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template
#
#  *** NOTE ***
#  If you customize the template file, make sure you keep an eye on the
#  original template file and merge any changes. New Phusion Passenger
#  features may require changes to the template file.
##############################################################

<%= include_passenger_internal_template('global.erb') %>

worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
    <%= include_passenger_internal_template('http.erb', 4) %>

    ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
    # This is a good place to put your own config
    # options. Note that your options must not
    # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
    # Learn more at:
    # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

    ### END your own configuration options ###

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;
    access_log off;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_min_length 150;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/json text/javascript
        application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
        application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf
        application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml text/xml;

    <% if @app_finder.multi_mode? %>
        # Default server entry for mass deployment mode.
        server {
            <%= include_passenger_internal_template('mass_deployment_default_server.erb', 12) %>
        }
    <% end %>

    <% for app in @apps %>
    server {
        <%= include_passenger_internal_template('server.erb', 8, true, binding) %>
        <%= include_passenger_internal_template('rails_asset_pipeline.erb', 8, false) %>

        ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
        # This is a good place to put your own config
        # options. Note that your options must not
        # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
        # Learn more at:
        # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

        ### END your own configuration options ###
    }
    passenger_pre_start <%= listen_url(app) %>;
    <% end %>

    <%= include_passenger_internal_template('footer.erb', 4) %>
}
```

Also I have confused where to put redirection code;

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mysite.co www.mysite.co;
        return 301 https://www.mysite.co$request_uri;
    }
```